# Does 'Android Market Application Error Report' depend on read sensitive log permission?

Tags: android, permissions

I have  error reports from two sources: Google market and my custom error reporting.
For my error reporting I use READ SENSITIVE LOG permission.
Does Google error report depend on this permission? My target is to use only Google reports  because many users complaint about this security permission.

**UPDATE**
Custom error report can contain more data than regular google report. As far as I know from my experience - to handle exception Google information is enought. If error is deeply hiden - error report isn't usefful anyway. If somebody have good advices how to put helpfull info in custom error log - please tell me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Google error reports does **not** require `android.permission.READ_LOGS` permission.